# AWS Rekognition Comparing Faces with images in folders

Tags: amazon-rekognition

I can compare two images if they are located in the root of the S3 bucket.

```
const params = {
  SourceImage: {
    S3Object: {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Name: 'source.jpg'
    }
  },
  TargetImage: {
    S3Object: {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Name: 'target.jpg'
    }
  },
  SimilarityThreshold: 90
}
```

But I get an error if they are in sub-folders:

> message: 'Request has invalid parameters',
>
> code: 'InvalidParameterException',
>
> time: 2019-11-25T13:12:44.498Z,
>
> requestId: '7ac7f297-fc36-436b-a1dc-113d419da766',
>
> statusCode: 400,
>
> retryable: false,   retryDelay: 71.0571139838835

If i try to compare images in sub-folders (note I tried with './', '/' before the path - same thing)

```
const params = {
  SourceImage: {
    S3Object: {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Name: '/sub1/sub2/source.jpg'
    }
  },
  TargetImage: {
    S3Object: {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Name: '/sub1/sub2/target.jpg'
    }
  },
  SimilarityThreshold: 90
}
```

I really need the photos to be in sub-folders. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example.

```
import boto3

reko=boto3.client('rekognition')

resp = reko.compare_faces(
        SourceImage={
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': 'jsimon-public-us',
            'Name': 'pref1/image1.jpg',
        }},
        TargetImage={
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': 'jsimon-public-us',
            'Name': 'pref2/image2.jpg',
        }}
)

print(resp)
```